# Calling db from a different project to get data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the scenario. I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I'm using entity framework 6 and I'm currently trying to create a console application that will run as a Windows Task Schedule that will send an email everyday to a specific person at a specific time.

To do this, I created a separate project within my solution that is a console application. I need to access the database that my asp.net mvc application uses so that I can get the proper person's email for the specified day.

What is the best way to do this? I tried to make a class in my asp.net mvc app that sets up DbContext and accesses the db and returns the results. But when I create an instance of this class in my console project and call the method to get a person by the date, it throws an exceptions `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`

This is the class I made in my asp.net mvc app.

```
public class DataService
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public DateTime GetDishDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return db.DishDates.Where(x => x.Date.Year == date.Year && x.Date.Month == date.Month).FirstOrDefault().Date;
    }

    public string GetPersonPhoneNumber(DateTime dishDate)
    {
        return db.DishDates.Where(x => x.Date == dishDate).FirstOrDefault().Person.PhoneNumber;
    }

    public string GetPersonPhoneCarrier(DateTime dishDate)
    {
        var phoneCarrierId = db.DishDates.Where(x => x.Date == dishDate).FirstOrDefault().Person.PhoneCarrier;
        return db.PhoneCarriers.Where(x => x.ID == phoneCarrierId).FirstOrDefault().EmailExtension;

    }
}
```

and this is the code in my console project that tries to utilize this "Service" class.

```
public void RunSchedule()
    {
        string email = "";

        // Find if a dish date exists for this day
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        var dishDate = dataService.GetDishDate(today);

        if (dishDate != null)
        {
            email = dataService.GetPersonPhoneNumber(dishDate) + "@" + dataService.GetPersonPhoneCarrier(dishDate);
        }

        // Send the email
        SendEmail(email);
    }
```

Again, when I execute the dataService.GetDishDate() is throws the aforementioned exception.

Any help or suggestions for how I should do this??? I guess I'm trying to access data from a different project, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you got your solution layered correctly? When you create solution with different project types, you should refactor out your Data Access Layer into separate project, and then reference it from both, ASP.NET MVC and your Console app. Try digging into Inner Exception to see what is actual reason of it. Maybe your app.config doesn't contain a copy of connection string?

Comment: Do I need to add a connection string to the app.config in my console app?

Comment: Yes, connection string is required in each app. Console application can't see your web.config file

Comment: The best approach is using `webApi` .